# How do I run multiple instances of regedit in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

The Windows Registry Editor only lets me run one instance, and if I try to start another while it's already running, it merely focuses the original one.  Is there a built-in way to allow multiple instances, such as a command line argument or a registry key in Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `/m` command line argument.  You can either run it through the Run dialog box or edit the shortcut in the Start Menu:

1. Right-click on Registry Editor in the Start Menu and click "Open File Location"
2. When Windows Explorer opens, right-click on the Registry Editor entry and choose "Properties"
3. Go to the Shortcut tab and change target from `%windir%\regedit.exe` to `%windir%\regedit.exe /m`
4. Choose "OK" to close the dialog

This will have the Registry Editor allow multiple instances by default.